# Ionic build say: Property '' does not exist on type ''

Tags: typescript, ionic3, leaflet

when I try to build this code in ionic3 it shows me this alert:
Property 'tempIcon' does not exist on type 'MapService'.

ionic build

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BaseLayersService } from "./base-layers.service";
import { WmsLayersService } from "./wms-layers.service";
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import L from "leaflet";

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
public map: L.Map;
constructor(private wmsLayersService: WmsLayersService, private baseLayersService: BaseLayersService, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
}
loadMap() {

  this.tempIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'assets/imgs/position.png',
        shadowUrl: '',
        iconSize: [48, 48], // size of the icon
        shadowSize: [0, 0], // size of the shadow
        iconAnchor: [48, 48], // point of the icon which will correspond to markers location
        shadowAnchor: [0, 0], // the same for the shadow
        popupAnchor: [48, 48] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });

const map = L.map("map", {
  //layers: [this.baseLayersService.baseLayers.OpenStreetMap, this.wmsLayersService.wmsLayers.Falabella]
   layers: [this.wmsLayersService.wmsLayers.Falabella, this.baseLayersService.baseLayers.CartoDB ] 
});

L.control.layers(this.baseLayersService.baseLayers, this.wmsLayersService.wmsLayers).addTo(map);
L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn t declare it. just try to declare it like

```
public map: L.Map;
public tempIcon: any;
```